# how to pass a global property to a child in vue3

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

i'm migrating a vue2 project to vue3
since global filters are not supported in the v3
i added them to themain.js file like this

```
app.config.globalProperties.$filters = {
  datetime,
  round,
};
```

now when i try to pass them in a child something like this :

```
<v-text-field  :value="$filters.datetime(model.name)
  " readonly dense hide-details class="flex-grow-0 mr-2" />
```

i'm getting this  ts error :

```
> Property '$filters' does not exist on type 'default'.ts(2339)
in the line "<v-text-field  :value="$filters.datetime(model.name)
```

" readonly dense hide-details class="flex-grow-0 mr-2" /"

what i'm i doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you read the docs, about thos breaking changes from 2 to 3 ?   https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/filters.html

Comment: "i'm getting this ts error " - where? The question doesn't show if you use TS. If you don't, then the problem is likely specific to IDE

Comment: @EstusFlask yes i did read the docs and i'm using ts

Comment: But the question says you use main.js. Otherwise see https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/options-api.html#augmenting-global-properties

Answer (score 0):

To fix your TypeScript issue, define your $filters in a new vue.d.ts file:

```
// vue.d.ts

import { datetime, round } from 'path-to-your-functions';

declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {
  interface ComponentCustomProperties {
    $filters: {
      datetime: typeof datetime,
      round: typeof round,
    };
  }
}
```

Now you can use $filters in child components:

```
<v-text-field :value="$filters.datetime(model.name)" readonly dense hide-details class="flex-grow-0 mr-2" />
```

Hope this helps!